# How else can I access a marketplace's product information via code?

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping

In order to scrape products off Ali Express, I can run **window.runParams.data** in Chrome's console to access all of the information very easily. Knowing this, I used regex to scrape product information directly from Ali Express's HTML without having to simulate a million clicks to make the information appear in my screen and only then extract it.

I am trying to do the same thing for another website called **Mercado Livre**. The thing is, each product can have variations, each of which may or may not have a whole other set of frequently more than 10 images. It's a lot of images and, unfortunately, I can't access **window.runParams.data** as I did for AliExpress. This is the error I get when I try:

```
VM228:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
    at <anonymous>:1:18
```

It probably doesn't matter but the variations section comes in **buttons**:

https://produto.mercadolivre.com.br/MLB-1870995603-brinquedos-sensoriais-popit-bubble-fidget-52-pecas-_JM

Or **dropdowns**:

https://produto.mercadolivre.com.br/MLB-1862560460-kit-brinquedos-sensoriais-fidget-push-pop-it-49-pcs-_JM

What is the easiest way to scrape all of these images' URLs using Python without having to simulat clicking? I looked at the code but I got very confused because many of the images are shared between variations so using Ctrl + F to look for URLs and try to find the location of each variation was impossible.

All of the thumbnail ones ([for example this one](https://http2.mlstatic.com/D_Q_NP_797952-CBT47229475737_082021-R.webp)) would suffice as I can just replace the R by an F at the end of the URL and it becomes large, [like this](https://http2.mlstatic.com/D_Q_NP_797952-CBT47229475737_082021-F.webp).

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using `requests` and `beautifulsoup`.

Upon clicking a variation of the product, the data is being loaded from an API. You can all the information from that API.

`prod_var_id` is the variation ID.

```html
https://produto.mercadolivre.com.br/p/api/items?attributes={prod_var_id}&quantity=1&platform=ML&id=MLB1870995603&app=vip
```

Here I have scraped the links of the variations of the product, extracted the `prod_var_id` from the link and making a get request to the API by substituting the `prod_var_id` in the API URL mentioned above.

> The `prod_var_id` is present in the URL after the `attributes=`

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36"}
url = 'https://produto.mercadolivre.com.br/MLB-1870995603-brinquedos-sensoriais-popit-bubble-fidget-52-pecas-_JM'

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
a = soup.find_all('a', class_='ui-pdp-thumbnail ui-pdp-variations--thumbnail ui-pdp-thumbnail--NONE')

prod_var_id = a[0]['href'].split('attributes=')[-1]
api_url = f'https://produto.mercadolivre.com.br/p/api/items?attributes={prod_var_id}&quantity=1&platform=ML&id=MLB1870995603&app=vip'
resp = requests.get(api_url).json()

print(api_url)
```

```
https://produto.mercadolivre.com.br/p/api/items?attributes=COLOR_SECONDARY_COLOR:NTJwY3MtMDE=&quantity=1&platform=ML&id=MLB1870995603&app=vip
```

You can make a request to this API and extract whatever data you need.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying! The trouble is none of the variation images were extracted using your approach. Each of the products has variations that you can access by clicking on the menu to the right. Each variation has multiple images of their own as well and there are two types of menu through which to access these variations (I have linked to an example of each). How can I access those via code without simulating clicks?

Comment: Ok. When you click any of those variations a request is being sent to an API. You can send the request to that API and get the data you need from it. See my updated answer.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much!! It works!! However, unfortunately it won't work for products that have a dropdown menu instead of button to select the variations such as for the second link. I tried to replace "ui-pdp-thumbnail ui-pdp-variations--thumbnail ui-pdp-thumbnail--NONE" with a few other class names but it didn't work. I'm really sorry to trouble you after you already helped me so much but could you help me make it work for dropdown menus also? Thanks again!